# Swift: how to convert a [String:Any] array to a specific array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, casting

I have this simple Struct:

```
protocol DocumentSerializable {
    init?(dictionary:[String:Any])
}

struct Item {
    var title:String
    var text:String?
    var dictionary:[String:Any] {
        return [
            "title":title,
            "text":text,
        ]
    }
}

extension Item : DocumentSerializable {
    init?(dictionary: [String : Any]) {
        guard let title = dictionary["title"] as? String,
            let text = dictionary["text"] as? String? else {return nil}

        self.init(title: title, text: text)
    }
}
```

When I recive my json, I put it in an array...

```
if let array = result?.data as? Array<[String:Any]> {...
```

How can I convert this array into an array of Items? `var itemsArray = [Item]()`

The two arrays have exactly the same structure

Thanks

Comment: You taggued with "Casting", but clearly, don't, you are misunderstanding what it does. Instead, do a loop and init each items with the dictionary at the corresponding index. Or use a more "Swifty" code, like `itemsArray = array.map({ Item.init(dictionary: $0) })`

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work. it returns me an empty array

Comment: Do you even pass the `if let` test? Are you sure that `result.data` is an Array of Dictionary? What's in `result.data`?

Comment: the print of array is: [["title": a title, "text": a text], ["title": a title, "text": a text],["title": a title, "text": a text]]

Comment: should be like this **[["title":"22222","text":"weewew"],["title":"22222","text":"weewew"]]**

Comment: I do not understand why it does not put the quotes

Comment: Does it pass if in your if let you do [String: String] ?

Comment: Yes, the quotes are there. But anyway, the other array remains empty

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
struct Item :Decodable {
 let title:String
 let text:String?
}
```

//

```
do {

    let root = try JSONDecoder().decode([Item].self, from:jsonData)

    print(root)

}
catch {

    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `compactMap`, it handles also the `nil` cases:

```
itemsArray = array.compactMap{ Item(dictionary: $0) }
```

However in Swift 4 it's highly recommended to use the `Codable` protocol

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work. it returns me an empty array

Comment: If your code passes the `if let` test successfully and contains dictionaries with `title` **and** `text` keys  my code is supposed to work.

Comment: I have simplified the properties here to make the code more readable. All the obligatory properties (title) come to me from the server. The optional properties are not all. and that's the problem?

Comment: According to the code the initializer creates an object only if **all** keys are available.

Comment: Thanks, now I will try with all the properties